# Pasar información de una variable JavaScript a una de PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Me gustaría obtener la información de la variable `a` y agregar esa información a la variable `recibir` de PHP

```js
var a = [];

function add() {
  a = document.querySelector("input").value;
  console.log("El nombre agregado es:" + " " + a);
}

// CÓMO PASAR LA INFORMACIÓN DE LA VARIABLE JAVASCRIPT A ESTA VARIABLE PHP

$recibir = '';
```

```html
<input type "text" placeholder="Nombre">
<button onclick="add()">Agregar</button>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

¿Has considerado la solución trivial de enviar los datos del formulario al hosting para que los procese el PHP?

```
<form>
<input type "text" placeholder="Nombre" name="recibir">
<button>Agregar</button>
</form>
```

Para que, en backend:

```
$recibir = $_GET['recibir'];
```

Otra opción sería crearte una API para procesarlo en asíncrono sin necesidad de recargar la página. Coméntanos qué buscas exactamente para poder ayudarte a decidirlo.

Answer (score 0):

tambien podrias enviarlo mediante ajax y recibir información de si se recibió la variable o no.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#boton', function(){
  let a = $("input").value;
  $.ajax({
    url:"procesar.php",
      method:"POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
      data: {name: a}, //esta es la variable que enviaras.
    succes: function(n){//te retornaria n con los datos en un array.
      //comprobar que se agrego.
      if(n.status == '200'){
        console.log("El nombre agregado es:" + " " + n.data);
      }else{
        console.log("Lo sentimos no se a podido agregar.");
      }
    }
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
<button id="boton">Agregar</button>
```

Solo te quedaria el php que procesaría los datos y te retornaria la respuesta, algo así:

```
<?php 
 $status = '';
 $data   = '';
 if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){// comprobar que se envien datos.
   $recibir = $_POST['name']; //la variable que querías.
   //hacer algo con $name.
   if(//lo que sea que hiciste){
     $status = 200; //todo bien.
     $data   = '';//lo que vas a enviar.
   }else{
     $status = 400; //error.
     $data   = '';//reporte de herrores.
   }
 }
 $results = array(
   'status' => $status,
   'data'   => $data
 );
?>
```